# Solution to session object static field problem

Tags: c#, session

In my code, I defined the session field statically in the past in order to be able to use it without creating objects in other sections with the code below, but now when there is different input from different computers, the object in the session looks the same for everyone and this is a huge problem.
Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks...

```
public static string getSessionKullaniciAdi()
  {
   try
   {
    return HttpContext.Current.Session["kullaniciadi"].ToString();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("kullanicigirisi.aspx");
    return null;
   }
  }
```

Comment: yes. C# (C-Sharp)

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem and ensure that session data is isolated for each user, you should use session variables in a non-static way.

```
public string getSessionKullaniciAdi()
{
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["kullaniciadi"] != null)
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["kullaniciadi"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("kullanicigirisi.aspx");
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("kullanicigirisi.aspx");
        return null;
    }
}
```

By removing the `static` keyword, the `getSessionKullaniciAdi` method will now operate on session data specific to each user.

Comment: I tried that, but when a different user logs in and sends a request to the server, the session data of the previous user is encountered again.

Comment: Check your application's session configuration is set up in  `web.config` file. Ensure that `mode` is set to `InProc` if you intend to use in-process session management.

Comment: In the web config file, the session field is organized as Inprog.